# How to Edit Task by Unique ID?

Tags: javascript, foreach, addeventlistener

I am trying to get the ID of the task when I click edit. The reason for this, is I want to use the ID from the `data-id="${task.id}"` that identifies each task created.

I have created a function that renders the task and it works:

```
taskArray.forEach((task) => {
        let divEl = document.createElement("div");
        divEl.classList.add("task-flex");
    
        divEl.innerHTML = `<div class="task-buttons">
            <img src="./resources/icons/edit.png" id="edit-button" alt="Edit Buttin"/>
            <img src="./resources/icons/bin.png" id="remove-button" alt="Bin Buttons" />
            <img src="./resources/icons/completed-task.png" id="complete-button" alt="Complete Task Button" />
          </div>
    
          <div class="task-to-do" data-id="${task.id}" data-value = "${task.timeStamp}">
              <div class="list" id="list-item-date">Due: ${task.date}</div>
              <div class="list" id="list-item-task">${task.task}</div>
          </div>`;
    
        taskListEl.append(divEl);
        
      });
```

This part I need assistance with.

I selected all of the `edit-buttons`, I then created a forEach loop for the `edit-button` in the forEach loop, I use the closest method to find the parent element of the edit button (**`editBtn`**)

This part is not working, its not doing anything in the console

```
// Event listener for edit buttons
    let editBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".edit-button");
    

    editBtns.forEach(editBtn => {
      let toDoTask = editBtn.closest(".task-to-do");
      let dataId = toDoTask.getAttribute("data-id");
      
      editBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          console.log(`Edit button clicked for task with data-id: ${dataId}`);
      });
  });
```

This is all one function

Comment: What happens when you log `toDoTask`? `closest()` find the closest *parent* node, so I believe your `toDoTask` is null since `editBtn` is *not* a child of `.task-to-do`. I would find the closest element that's a [grand]parent of BOTH and then use querySelector() to find the `.task-to-do`: `let grandparent = editBtn.closest(selectorToFindNearestCommonRelative); let toDoTask = grantparent.querySelector(".task-to-do");`

Comment: Also, you have no elements with `class="edit-button"`. Only with `id="edit-button"` If you were to log `editBtns`, you'd see it's empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the event listeners to each task's div (`divEl`) directly in the forEach loop. But instead of assigning an id to each img, you can for example use `data-` attribute to designate the actions. In your example, each icon image would get the same `id` for each task, which is not good practice. Maybe you meant `class`?

You would then define functions to handle edit, remove and complete actions, where the id of the task is passed as a variable from the event listener function. Here is an example:

```js
const taskArray = [
  { id: 1, timeStamp: '1234', date: '01/01/01', task: 'Task 1' },
  { id: 2, timeStamp: '1234', date: '01/01/01', task: 'Task 2' },
  { id: 3, timeStamp: '1234', date: '01/01/01', task: 'Task 3' }
]

const taskListEl = document.getElementById('taskList')

taskArray.forEach((task) => {
  let divEl = document.createElement('div')

  divEl.classList.add('task-flex')
  divEl.innerHTML = `<div class="task-buttons">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImN1cnJlbnRDb2xvciIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcD0icm91bmQiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lam9pbj0icm91bmQiIGNsYXNzPSJsdWNpZGUgbHVjaWRlLXBlbmNpbCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTE3IDNhMi44NSAyLjgzIDAgMSAxIDQgNEw3LjUgMjAuNSAyIDIybDEuNS01LjVaIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTE1IDUgNCA0Ii8+PC9zdmc+"
      data-action="edit" alt="Edit Buttin"/>
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImN1cnJlbnRDb2xvciIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcD0icm91bmQiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lam9pbj0icm91bmQiIGNsYXNzPSJsdWNpZGUgbHVjaWRlLXRyYXNoIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMyA2aDE4Ii8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTE5IDZ2MTRjMCAxLTEgMi0yIDJIN2MtMSAwLTItMS0yLTJWNiIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik04IDZWNGMwLTEgMS0yIDItMmg0YzEgMCAyIDEgMiAydjIiLz48L3N2Zz4="
      data-action="remove" alt="Bin Buttons" />
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImN1cnJlbnRDb2xvciIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcD0icm91bmQiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lam9pbj0icm91bmQiIGNsYXNzPSJsdWNpZGUgbHVjaWRlLWNoZWNrIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMjAgNiA5IDE3bC01LTUiLz48L3N2Zz4="
      data-action="complete" alt="Complete Task Button" />
  </div>

  <div class="task-to-do" data-id="${task.id}" data-value = "${task.timeStamp}">
      <div class="list" id="list-item-date">Due: ${task.date}</div>
      <div class="list" id="list-item-task">${task.task}</div>
  </div>`

  divEl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    switch (event.target.dataset.action) {
      case 'edit':
        editTask(task.id)
        break
      case 'remove':
        removeTask(task.id)
        break
      case 'complete':
        completeTask(task.id)
        break
    }
  })

  taskListEl.append(divEl)
})

function editTask(id) {
  console.log('Edit task id ' + id)
}

function removeTask(id) {
  console.log('Remove task id ' + id)
}

function completeTask(id) {
  console.log('Complete task id ' + id)
}
```

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Arial';
 font-size: 12px;
}
.task-buttons img {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .task-flex {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 
 .task-to-do {
  display: flex;
 }
 
 .list {
  margin-left: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="taskList"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are your mistakes:

1. You can't use more than one unique id on the page (id="edit-button");
   To fix this point just replase `id="edit-button"` with `class="edit-button"`;
2. This selector "document.querySelectorAll(".edit-button")" is supposed to select all elements with class name "edit-button". This won't work in your current implementation. When you fix the #1 point it will work.
3. In this line `let toDoTask = editBtn.closest(".task-to-do")` you are trying to get parent element with classname "task-to-do" of the "editBtn" element. But your div with "task-to-do" classname isn't parent of it, but a sibling one.

Here is my variant:

1. Creating an array of tasks.

```
taskArray.forEach((task) => {
  const divEl = document.createElement("div");
  const uniqueId = task.id;
  divEl.classList.add("task-flex");
  divEl.id = uniqueId;
  divEl.innerHTML = `
    <div class="task-buttons">
     <button class="edit-button" data-action="edit" data-id=`${uniqueId}`>
      <img src="./resources/icons/edit.png" alt="Edit Buttin"/>
     </button>
     <button class="remove-button" data-action="remove" data-id=`${uniqueId}`>
      <img src="./resources/icons/bin.png" alt="Bin Buttons" />
     </button>
     <button class="complete-button" data-action="complete" data-id=`${uniqueId}`>
      <img src="./resources/icons/completed-task.png" alt="Complete Task Button" />
     </button>
    </div>
    <div class="task-to-do" data-id="${task.id}" data-value="${task.timeStamp}">
      <div class="list" id=`${uniqueId}-list-item-date`>Due: ${task.date}</div>
      <div class="list" id=`${uniqueId}-list-item-task`>${task.task}</div>
    </div>`;
   taskListEl.append(divEl); 
});
```

2.Event Listeners.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".task-flex")].forEach((task) => {
  [...task.querySelectorAll("button")].forEach((button) => {
    const action = button.getAttribute("data-action");
    const taskId = button.getAttribute("data-id");
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(`Action: ${action} for ID: ${taskId}`);
    });
  });
});
```